# There is no " Object Tools" it just says Transform

Tags: interface

[image: No Object Tools]

I apologize for the newbie Question and if this was the wrong site to post this Question I have tried to search not doing that right either,I have no idea what i`m doing following  tutor4u " realistic chain tutorial" I can make it to 8:37 into the tutorial, need to add  "Rigid Body Tools" My tools bar is saying "Transform" instead of "Object Tools"
 My Learning Curve Begins/ Continues/ Never Ends

Thank-you for any advice

Wally

Comment: Thank-you all for the Quick reply and Great information,I really appreciate your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'minus' that you refer to was removed in 2.70, you can now do the same thing by right clicking on one of the menus and choosing `Header -> Collapse menus`

The tools sidebar has also had tabs added to it, which you can find along the left side. The rigid body tools you are looking for can be found in the `Physics` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The UI has probably changed since the tutorial was made. Blender moves and changes UI elements quite often.

*Rigid Body Tools* is in the *Physics* tab. The *Objects* section is pretty much the *Transform* section, just with the title renamed. Make sure you're in the proper mode when you're looking around (i.e., mesh Edit mode vs Object mode).